# How to set logFile path dynamically for different modules in yii

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-components

I want to set different logpath for each module so that all errors, warnings, should be categorize with module name as parent folder.

i.e

> runtime/logs/module_name/errors.log
>
> runtime/logs/module_name/warnings.log
>
> runtime/logs/module_name/info.log.

currently log component is configured in config/main.php

```
    'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'flushInterval' => 1,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['info'],
                'categories' => ['common\modules\*'],
                'logFile' => '@runtime/logs/common.modules.info.log',  
            ],
      ],
]
```

I want to dynamically assign logFile path value in above application configuration file, so that if any error, warning, info is called in any module it will automatically pick that module name and logs the information.

Comment: I'm not aware of dynamic change possibility. You might need to temporarily solve this by writing everything manually.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas there must be some way around, instead of writing everything.....

Comment: I honestly can't answer this question. Sorry. :( I just wrote everything by hand (but didn't take very long).

Answer (score 0):

You can add log target dynamically from controller or module init.

```
$target = new FileTarget();
$target->logFile = \Yii::getAlias('@runtime') . '/custom.log'
$target->categories = ['log-category']
\Yii::$app->getLog()->targets = [$target];
```

But I think will be better create new FileTarget class and moved static settings like categories into it.